# Check if the s3 object is already been picked by another thread java

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-s3

I am having a scheduled task which keeps checking in an s3 bucket , picks all the entries at a time and does the processing.
My task is running at an interval of 10 seconds. I delete the object immediately after I read it. Still sometimes same object is being picked by multiple tasks. How can I avoid this ?

```
public void execute(){

AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = readEmailsAndMoveToRead(s3, incomingBucket, customerId);
        if (summaries != null)
                for (S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary : summaries) {
                    String key = s3ObjectSummary.getKey();// getting the key of
                                                            // the item
                    try {
                        S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(incomingBucket, key));
                        InputStream mailFileInputStream = object.getObjectContent();
                        String bucketKey = object.getKey();
                        s3.deleteObject(incomingBucket, bucketKey);
                        MimeMessage message = getMimeMessageForRawEmailString(mailFileInputStream);
                        object.close();
                        boolean isProcessed = processMessage(message);
                        if (isProcessed) {
                            logger.logDebug(CLASSNAME, "Processed successfully");

                        } else {
                            logger.logError(CLASSNAME, "Processing Error");

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        logger.logDebug(CLASSNAME, "This s3 object is already processed and deleted");
                    }

                }
}
```

Comment: There isn't anything in S3 itself to help you, here, since there consistency model of S3 does not guarantee that deleted objects will never appear in a subsequent object listing... but if you are reading new emails and these are written by SES, why do you not collect notification events in an SQS queue (via SES > SNS > SQS for example), rather than polling the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a Latch or a mutex, in order to block other tasks when one is already using the object ? You should also check that your methods are thread-safe before using them in a multi-threaded environment.

e: You should read some stuff on concurrency if you are not familiar with it, it is not straight forward at all: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: I think "object" in the question refers to an object stored in S3, rather than a programmatic object.  OP is fetching a list of those objects from S3, iterating through the list, processing and deleting objects, potentially unaware that listing objects is an eventually-consistent operation that may contain very recently deleted objects which, in some cases may even still be fetchable, since the delete action itself is an eventually-consistent operation. [Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html).

Comment: Oh OK. So its a problem of transactions then.

Comment: Not precisely, since S3 isn't transactional per se, but that's not a bad analogy.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel the service is apparently being used here in a way that's a little bit outside its design specification.  Listing objects after deleting objects *may* (briefly) return lists that include deleted objects.  Or... I may be reading too much into the question and your answer may be closer than I assume.  That's why no downvote.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the info and links.